# Computing a very messy contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm hoping that someone might be able to help me with the following problem. I'll walk through my current work and indicate where I'm stuck.

> Compute the contour integral:
>
> $$ \oint_{|z-1-i| = 5/4} \frac{Log(z)}{(z-1)^2} \, dz. $$

Clearly, the curve represents a circle of radius $5/4$ centered at the point $z_0 = 1 + i$. After drawing the curve, I've noticed that its interior contains two singularities, namely $z=0$ (where $Log(z)$ is undefined) and $z=1$ (where the denominator of the integrand is undefined).

Let $C$ be the curve represented by $|z-1-i| = 5/4$ and let $D$ be the interior of $C$. My first step is to split the region $D$ into two pieces:

$$
D_1 = \left\{ z \in D \ | \ Im(z) < 1/2 \right\}$
$$

$$
D_2 = \left\{ z \in D \ | \ Im(z) > 1/2 \right\}.
$$

Let $C_1$ be the boundary of $D_1$ and let $C_2$ be the boundary of $D_2$. Now we have

$$
\oint_{|z-1-i| = 5/4} \frac{Log(z)}{(z-1)^2} \, dz = \oint_{C_1} \frac{Log(z)}{(z-1)^2} \, dz + \oint_{C_2} \frac{Log(z)}{(z-1)^2} \, dz.
$$

To compute the second integral, note that $Log(z)$ is analytic in $D_2$, and so we can apply the modified version of the Cauchy integral formula. We have

$$
\oint_{C_2} \frac{Log(z)}{(z-1)^2} \, dz = 2\pi i \cdot f'(1)
$$

where $f(z) = Log(z)$. Since $f'(z) = 1/z$, $f'(1) = 1$ and so the integral is equal to $2\pi i$.

Finally we need to compute the first integral. Note that $D_1$ contains a singularity of $Log(z)$, namely $z=0$. We construct a circle of radius $0.25$ centered at the origin. Since $Log(z)$ is analytic on the rest of $D_1$, the value of the whole integral is just the value of

$$
\oint_{C'} \frac{Log(z)}{(z-1)^2} \, dz
$$

where $C'$ is the circle of radius $0.25$ centers at the origin.

Here's where I'm running into trouble -- namely in parametrizing the circle $C'$. Am I even on the right path toward a solution?

Comment: $z=0$ is not inside the contour.

Comment: Ah! Silly mistake on my part. Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Consider $w=z-1$. The integral becomes
$$
\oint_{|w-i|=5/4}\frac{\log(1+w)}{w^2}\mathrm{d}w
$$
Recall the power series for $\log(1+w)=w-\frac{w^2}{2}+\frac{w^3}{3}-\dots$

Since $w=0$ *is* inside the contour, we can apply the [Residue Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).

---

**Comment:** There is nothing wrong with your approach using [Cauchy's Integral Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula). We are both actually looking at the first derivative of $\log(z)$ at $z=1$. However, you don't need to break up the contour.

**Caveat:** be careful about considering $\log(z)$ on contours which circle the origin.

$\hspace{4.5cm}$[image]